# KendoGrid Disable or Enable (edit, add or delete button) base (true or false in )

Tags: jquery, button, kendo-ui

I want to disable or enable the button (k-grid-edit, k-grid-add, k-grid-delete) in Kendo Grid base a value (true or false) get from controller (viewbag or viewdata).

That value are got from a function in action base usertype....

Answer (score 4):

```
columns.Command(command => command.Destroy())
.HtmlAttributes( new { @class = (bool)ViewBag.Disabled ? "k-state-disabled" : "k-state-default"})
```

Note: You amy have to manually detach the click event of individual buttons for this css trick. Following would be helpful instead:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Visible((bool)ViewBag.IsDisabled))
```

or `columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Hidden((bool)ViewBag.IsDisabled))`

Comment: Wonderfull.. I am test.. Thanks much ! Binbsr

Comment: If that solves your problem, you are always free to accept the answer :) so that others can easily notice the reliability.

Answer (score 0):

For change kendo-grid setting, you must re-create your grid.  [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418282/3631230).  I hope this could help you.