# Kendo Grid Hiding/Showing Delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am new to Kendo MVC components as well as to jQuery.

I am building a Kendo grid. I would like to hide the destroy (delete) command in the grid on page load. After that, when I click a button on the page, it should be visible.

Kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>() 
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(product => product.DESCRIPTION).Title("Description");
        columns.Bound(product => product.CODE).Title("Description");
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Destroy().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "buttondelete" }); 
        }).Title("Operations");
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create().Text("Add Records"); 
        toolbar.Save(); 
    })
                                 
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)) 
    .Pageable(pager => pager
        .PageSizes(true)
        .Input(true)
        .Refresh(true)
    )
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Events(events => events.Error("onError"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(product => product.ID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
            model.Field(p => p.DESCRIPTION).Editable(false);
            model.Field(product => product.CODE).Editable(false);
        })
        .Create(create => create.Action("a", "www")) 
        .Read(read => read.Action("b", "www"))  
        .Update(update => update.Action("c", "www"))  
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("d", "www")) 
    )
)
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#grid").find(".k-grid-delete").hide() // hide delete button
        $("#grid").find(".k-toolbar").hide(); // hide toolbar
        $(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").hide();
    });
    
    $('#EnableEdit').click(function () {
        $("#grid").find(".k-toolbar").show();
        
        // $(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").show();
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.at(0).fields["CODE"].editable = true;
        grid.dataSource.at(0).fields["DESCRIPTION"].editable = true;
    });

</script>
```

Edit: changed some parts according to first answer. Now
`$(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").hide();` cannot hide k.grid-delete class. I guess JavaScript is loaded before the kendo grid is created. When I use it inside the click function of the edit button, it hides the delete buttons.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the same `id` for each columns you have many elements with the same `id` which is not *legal*. Try using the CSS class attribute that identifies a `delete` button and on creation (page load) hide it and then on click show it.

Code for hiding them

```
$(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").hide();
```

Code for showing them back

```
$('#EnableEdit').click(function () {
    $(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").show();
});
```

JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/pSgeD/

Comment: Thanks for answer,for some reason $(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").hide() function cannot hide .k-grid-delete css class.I tried to use it on inside $(document).ready(function (){   });  , still no use.When i use it like this:

$('#EnableEdit').click(function () {
    $(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").hide();
});

It hides the button when i click the button.

Comment: You need to do the `$(".k-grid-delete", "#grid").hide()` after creating the Grid, not valid just in `$(document).ready(function (){ });` because the Grid is also create on `ready`. You need to make sure that this is executed __after__ the Grid is initialized. Another possibility is doing it on `dataBinding` event.

Answer (score 3):

For change kendo-grid setting, you must re-create your grid. You can comment out "for offlide data",  if you gird binding to remote data.

```
setGridReadOnly: function (gridId, isReadOnly) {

    var grid;

    grid = $("#" + gridId).data("kendoGrid");

    var myOpt = grid.options;
    myOpt.editable.create = !isReadOnly;
    myOpt.editable.destroy = !isReadOnly;
    myOpt.editable.update = !isReadOnly;
    if (isReadOnly == true)
        myOpt.editable.mode = "null";
    else
        myOpt.editable.mode = "inline";

    //for offlide data.
    var data = grid._data;
    //

    grid.destroy();

    $("#" + gridId).kendoGrid(myOpt).data("kendoGrid");

    //for offlide data.
    $("#" + gridId).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(data);
    //

    if (isReadOnly == true) {
        $("#" + gridId).find(".k-grid-delete").hide();
        $("#" + gridId).find(".k-grid-edit").hide();
        $("#" + gridId).find(".k-grid-add").hide();
    } else {
        $("#" + gridId).find(".k-grid-delete").show();
        $("#" + gridId).find(".k-grid-edit").show();
        $("#" + gridId).find(".k-grid-add").show();
    }

}
```