# Disable command by data condition in kendogrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How can I disable the Delete Button on a row by a given boolean?

Given this example Model:

```
public class Example
{
    public bool CanDeleted {get; set;} //Delete Button only if true
    //...        
}
```

`KendoGrid<Example>`:

```
columns.Command(c => c.Destroy()); //I want something something like m => m.CanDeleted
```

Comment: Did you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19840309/1876572

Comment: @Eldho, yes i have taken a look at it. But it seems like, this disables/enables all rows on serverside. My concern is about client side based on the data, not the ViewBag/ViewModel.

Comment: Take a look at this too http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-conditional-set-the-visibility-of-the-command-edit-button-on-a-row-by-row-basis-

Comment: Thank you @Eldho. This looks good :)

Comment: Try it out and let me know your feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing the situation with a little bit more knowledge about MVC, I found a signficant better solution, using a Extension Method:

```
public static class KendoExtensions
{
    public static GridTemplateColumnBuilder<TModel> DestroyConditional<TModel>(this GridColumnFactory<TModel> factory, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
        where TModel : class
    {
        var template = "# if (" + ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression) +") { # <a class=\"k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete\"><span class=\"k-icon k-delete\"></span>" + TextStrings.Delete + "</a># } #";

        return factory.Template(e => "").ClientTemplate(template).Title("");
    }
}
```

Feel free to replace `TextStrings.Delete` to whatever you feel good. Its simple my T4 Localization Logic.

Now in your grid definition it's realy just:

```
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.DestroyConditional(c => c.CanBeDeleted).Width(120);
}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Eldho, who has pointed me to the [right solution](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-conditional-set-the-visibility-of-the-command-edit-button-on-a-row-by-row-basis-)

Javascript:

```
function onDataBound() {
    var grid = $("#GridID").data("kendoGrid"); //Set GridID
    var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {
        var gridItem = gridData[i];
        if (!gridItem.CanBeDeleted) { //Condition
            grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + gridItem.uid + "']").find(".k-grid-delete").hide(); //Remove button
        }

        //Second Iteration, if we have grouped columns
        if (gridItem.items) {
            for (var j = 0; j < gridItem.items.length; j++) {
                var gridSubItem = gridItem.items[j];
                if (!gridSubItem.CanBeDeleted) { //Condtion
                    grid.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + gridSubItem.uid + "']").find(".k-grid-delete").hide(); //Remove button
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KendoGrid Helper :

```
.Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
```

Look at my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45178680/2441442) for a better solution.